# Custom Async Validator to validate email from backend api called getting called multiple times on page load

Tags: angular

I am creating a custom validator to validate email from the backend api call.
When the register component loads the api is already called multiple times this I can see in the console. I only want it to be called it on submit.

Public Service

```
validateEmail(email: string) {
    this.newHttp = new HttpClient(this.handler);
    return this.newHttp.get(this.isVerifiedApi+'/'+email);
  }
```

Validator

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { PublicService } from '../services/public.service';

    export class CheckEmail {
      static createValidator(publicService: PublicService) {
        return (control: AbstractControl) => {
          return publicService.isVerified(control.value).subscribe((res: any)=>{
              console.log(res);
              console.log(res);
              return 'validEmail';
          },(err: any)=>{
              console.log(err);
              return 'null';
          });
        };
      }
    }
```

Register component html

```
 <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls.email.hasError('validEmail')" data-tip="Email is not valid"></div> 
   <input (focus)="emailExistsHide()" [ngClass]="{'face error-border': registerForm.get('email').invalid && registerForm.get('email').touched || registerForm.get('email').invalid && registerForm.get('email').invalid && submitted }" type="text" (focus)="focusEmailInput()" formControlName="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" tabindex="3"/>
```

Register component ts

```
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, CheckEmail.createValidator(this.publicService)]],

....
....
onSubmit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.submitted = true;
    ...............
```

Comment: Side note: You **must** URL-encode any user-supplied data. Using this `this.isVerifiedApi+'/'+email` as a URL is wrong and a run-time bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it focus out event it is the good approach

**Working** [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8lpni5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
youFocusOutFunction()
  {
    console.log('Focus out fired');
      // this.newHttp = new HttpClient(this.handler);
      // return this.newHttp.get(this.isVerifiedApi+'/'+email);
  }


  yourFocusFunction()
  {
    console.log('Focus fired');
  }
```

or it can be done

```
doEmailValidation() {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("email validation")
     // this.newHttp = new HttpClient(this.handler);
      // return this.newHttp.get(this.isVerifiedApi+'/'+email);
  });
  return promise;
}


submit()
{
 this.doEmailValidation().then(() =>
 //do your submit task
  console.log("submit task!"));
}
```

Comment: in Angular you can explicity {updateOn:'blur'} when you create the Reactive Form, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance